# Need to sort task depending upon the parent task

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, breadth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

Need to sort task such that, It should come in sequence once parent of the task is listed down. It can be approached as a Directed Acyclic Graph(DAG)

In this particular example,
The main issue is:
 "13        ifhj        5,4,9,15" should always come after 5,4,9 and 15.But 13 is coming before 15.

I am providing sample input and expected output.

I/p:

```
task_no    t_name     Parent_Task_Numbers
    1       task1       0
    2       task2       0
    3       task3       0
    4       task4       1,2
    5       task5       0
    6       task6       2
    7       task7       4
    8       task8       6,1,4
    9       task9       10
    10      task10      1
    11      task11      2
    12      task12      3
    13      task13      5,4,9,15
    15      task15      7,8,2,10
```

Expected o/p:(This can be different than this, but the main idea should be served)

```
task_no    t_name     Parent_Task_Numbers
    1       task1       0
    2       task2       0
    3       task3       0
    5       task5       0
    10      task10      1
    4       task4       1,2
    9       task9       10
    6       task6       2
    11      task11      2
    12      task12      3
    7       task7       4
    15      task15      7,8,2,10
    13      task13      5,4,9,15
    8       task8       6,1,4
```

```
def sort_parent_tasks1(fileName):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(fileName)
    print("df1.Parent_Task_Numbers.str.split(',')", type(df1.Parent_Task_Numbers.str.split(',')))
    df1.Parent_Task_Numbers.str.split(',').apply(sorted, reverse = True).str.join(',').str.strip(',')
    df3 = df1.sort_values(['Parent_Task_Numbers'])
    df3.to_csv("/fileData/task_files/output/test_generated1.csv")


inputFile = "/fileData/task_files/input/test.csv"
sort_parent_tasks1(inputFile)
```

What I am getting is: which is WRONG.

```
tasknumber    taskname    Parent_Task_Numbers
1       task1       0
2       task2       0
3       task3       0
5       task5       0
10      task10      1
4       task4       1,2
9       task9       10
6       task6       2
11      task11      2
12      task12      3
7       task7       4
13      task13      5,4,9,15
8       task8       6,1,4
15      task15      7,8,2,1
```

Comment: Please review [ask], and create a [mcve], that means no images of code!  Also reviewing [how to create good, reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) would be helpful here.

Comment: got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking input from  https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/dag_dependencies.html

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd



def create_DAG(abs_file = "input.csv"):
    G2 = nx.DiGraph()
    df1 = pd.read_csv(abs_file)
    print(df1)

    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        print("row['tasknumber']" , row['tasknumber'], "row['Parent_Task_Numbers']", row['Parent_Task_Numbers'])
        parents = row['Parent_Task_Numbers'].split(",")
        for p in parents:
            G2.add_edge(int(p), int(row['tasknumber']))

    nodes = df1["tasknumber"].tolist()
    map(G2.add_node, nodes)

    for item in nodes:
            print("successors of {} is {}".format(item, list(G2.successors(item))))

    # now draw the graph:
    nx.draw(G2, with_labels=True, edge_color='r')
    plt.show()
    print("graph printed ")

    return G2


G2 = create_DAG()

order = nx.topological_sort(G2)
print("order :", order)
abs_file = "input.csv"
df2 = pd.read_csv(abs_file)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df2.columns)

for task in order:
    row1 = df2.loc[df2['tasknumber'] == task]
    df3 = df3.append(row1, ignore_index=True)


print("rearranged data frame is : ", df3)
```